# Solo permitir INT, FLOAT, COMPLEX en un Input con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero hacer que de un input pueda saber que tipo de dato es, por ejemplo, Int, Float o Complex, para luego solo pueda ingresar ese primer tipo de dato, he intentado con Try e isinstance, pero sin éxito. Esto porque desde el input ya va como string.

```
i = input("Ingrese: ")
x = isinstance(i, (int, float, complex))
print(x)
```

Cualquier ayuda muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente `input()` te devuelve una cadena. Aunque las cadenas tienen el método `.isnumeric()`, éste sólo serviría para verificar si la cadena representa un entero, pero no sirve para float o complex.

La mejor solución es intentar convertir la cadena a los diferentes tipos a ver si se puede. Si no se puede, se generará una excepción. Esto nos permite escribir una función que reciba la cadena a validar y una lista de tipos, y vaya probando a convertir a cada uno de esos tipos de uno en uno. Tan pronto como tiene éxito, devuelve el resultado. Si en cambio se produce una excepción la ignora y pasa a intentar el siguiente tipo. Si agota la lista de tipos sin éxito, retorna un valor especial que indica que el dato no es válido (por ejemplo, `None`).

Esta función sería así:

```
def validar(dato, tipos):
  for tipo in tipos:
    try:
      return tipo(dato)
    except ValueError:
      pass
  return None
```

Por ejemplo, si la llamas con `validar("23", (int, float, complex))` te retornaría el entero `23`. Si la llamas en cambio con `validar("Hola", (int, float, complex))` te retornaría `None`.

Esto permite replicar el código de ejemplo que ponías en la pregunta:

```
i = input("Ingrese: ")
x = validar(i, (int, float, complex))
if x is None:
  print("Dato no numérico")
else:
  print(x)
```

Naturalmente puedes usar esto dentro de un bucle que insista en pedir el dato al usuario hasta que éste introduzca un dato válido:

```
while True:
  i= input("Introduzca numero: ")
  x = validar(i, (int, float, complex))
  if x is None:
    print("El dato no es numérico")
  else:
    break

print("Dato introducido:", x)
```

### Actualización

Para lo que se me pregunta en un comentario (que la segunda vez que se obtenga un input se admita sólo el mismo tipo que la primera vez), basta pasarle a la función `validar()` el tipo deseado (aunque espera una lista de ellos, por lo que habría que pasarle una lista aún si contiene un solo elemento).

Por ejemplo, para evitar anidar bucles, primero escribo una función que lee un solo dato, pero insiste hasta que lo introducido sea del tipo esperado:

```
def leer_tipo_correcto(tipos):
  while True:
    i= input("Introduzca numero: ")
    x = validar(i, tipos)
    if x is None:
      print("El dato no es del tipo correcto")
    else:
      return x
```

Ahora hacemos otro bucle para llamar a esa función, pasándole los tipos apropiados. La primera vez serán tres, pero las veces siguientes ya será solo uno, en particular el tipo del dato leido antes:

```
tipos_validos = [int, float, complex]
while True:
  x = leer_tipo_correcto(tipos_validos)
  print("Valor leido:", x)
  tipos_validos = [type(x)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, ha funcionado perfecto. Una última pregunta, podría en el segundo intento solo permitir el tipo de dato ingresado la primera vez, es decir, la primera vez puedo ingresar cualquier tipo (int, float, complex) menos enteros, la siguiente vez solo puedo ingresar el tipo de datos ingresado la primera vez. Nuevamente gracias

Comment: @daguirre Mira a ver si la actualización responde esto que me pides ahora.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia, anda muy bien el código te agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera poco práctica (pero efectiva) de hacerlo podría ser:

```
def convertir_a_numero(i: str):
  if i.isdigit():
    return int(i)
  elif '.' in i:
    return float(i)
  elif 'j' in i:
    return complex(i)
  else:
    return None
```

También podrías intentar con funciones similares en combinaciones de `try-except`, o revisar la clase genérica `Number` en [PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/). Espero que alguna de estas propuestas funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado también

Comment: Entonces "0..1023" es `float` y `juan perez` es complejo ...

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es tratar de convertirlo. Si la conversión falla, intentar con la siguiente conversión en orden int->float->complex.

La función `ingresar` lee desde el teclado hasta recibir un valor numérico. La función retorna el valor numérico correspondiente.

Para chequear que sea del tipo numérico, se utiliza `try - except`. Si la conversión falla, se ejecuta el `except`, donde se reintenta la siguiente conversión en orden. Cuando todo falla, se imprime un mensaje de error y se vuelve a pedir la entrada:

```
def ingresar():
    while True:
        x = input("Valor:")
        try:
            valor = int(x)
            break
        except ValueError:
            try:
                valor = float(x)
                break
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    valor = complex(x)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("no es un valor numérico. Reintente.")
    return valor
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado también